# How to Display the mean/median/mode values of a given series data in HighCharts

Tags: java, jquery, highcharts

I want to display the mean value of a series data in highcharts. I would also like to display a tolerance(+/-) on the mean value of the series data. I searched for relevant API or posts online. But came across none. Any inputs would be great. Thanks.

Comment: This is not supported directly by Highcharts. You need to preprocess data to calculate values, and create new series.

Comment: @Pawel Fus thx Pawel. It would be a nice to have feature :)

Comment: Use uservoice to vote for such features. If idea doesn't exist - create one.